# Typescript check if function parameter is optional

Tags: typescript

I have the following objects:

```
const object1 = {
  foo(a?: any) {}
}

const object2 = {
  foo(a: any) {}
}
```

Is there any way to know whether the parameter passed to the foo function is optional?

I only know how to get if it doesn't have params:

```
type NoParams = Parameters<typeof object['foo']> extends [] ? true : false
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr3G1m) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm:

- Write a type that accepts a generic parameter constrained by any function
- Store parameters of the function in the inferred parameter constrained by `unknown[]` `Params`
- Call recursive type `Traverse` and pass `Params` to it to check the parameters one by one:

  - If the array is empty return true
  - Retrieve the first element from the array
  - If the first element extends its required version (without optionality) it  means that the element itself is not optional:

    - Return false;
  - Else:

    - Call the `Traverse` for the rest of the `Params`.

Implementation:
We are going to use [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) keyword, which will allow us to store the parameters in a separate parameter and retrieve elements from the array.

```
type Traverse<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [
  infer First,
  ...infer Rest extends unknown[]
]
  ? First extends Required<First>
    ? false
    : Traverse<Rest>
  : true;

type HasNoRequiredParams<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
  Parameters<T> extends infer Params extends unknown[]
    ? Traverse<Params>
    : never;
```

Testing:

```
// true
type Case1 = HasNoRequiredParams<(arg?: string) => void>;
// false
type Case2 = HasNoRequiredParams<(arg: string) => void>;
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwG4TgZwgHhlCAPYCAOwBM0oBXIgayIHsB3IgbQF0A+KAXllwOLJRmAWABQUKAEsiAM1RQAYpPTAANGIkA6bdLlwoAJQhpgfQqXJVajFqzF3xUAPyLlJswPJGAjhWUQSTCUVdg0JZygZBAAbDDCJAC5YRBR0LCMTUMck4DgKCABuMTFQSCgACQQ0ADk6Hz84AIAFBEQAWzRsDwsoAAptTVaAczQkhCIQNgBKbk5xkE4uMJb2iEJ0bE58c0FdeRWEDu7BK3omNniI+GRUDEwDjqzwqCSiCFSi0TEAem+oXPyJXA0AAwlUIABGbgVKq1er+EgPTq9YZOJImODSIYzLicJB0SQkdifX6RGJxUSlUHggBM0MqNTqEF8CKRmBRcCG6NyWJxeIJRM+QA)